# Django Serializers not parsing foreign key objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the models:

```
 class employees(models.Model):
  emp_id=models.PositiveIntegerField()
  emp_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
  manager_id=models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)

class leave(models.Model):  
  employee = models.ForeignKey(employees, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
  start_date = models.DateField()
  end_date = models.DateField()

class notify(models.Model):
 sender_id=models.ForeignKey(leave, related_name='%(class)s_sendername')
 receiver_id=models.ForeignKey(leave,related_name='%(class)s_receivername')
 viewed=models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

In my views I am writing Query as:

```
def notification(request):
  template = loader.get_template('base.html')
  user = employees.objects.get(emp_id=request.user.username)
  emp_id=user.emp_id;
  notification=notify.objects.filter(receiver_id__employee__emp_id=emp_id);
  data = serializers.serialize("json", notification)
  print(data);
  context={'notification':data,'notification_count':notification_count}
  femp = json.dumps(context)
  return JsonResponse(femp, safe=False, content_type="text/html")
```

In print(data) its printing

```
 [{"model": "apply.notify", "pk": 32,
  "fields": {"sender_id": 121, "receiver_id": 44, "viewed": "N"}}]
```

Here its printing the sender_id=121 which is id in leave table but if I want start_date and emp_name(as it is referenced from employee in leave table).What should I write in serializers.serialize()so that I can reference foreign key enteties.

Answer (score 0):

for this you can use natural keys.
the link is here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization/#natural-keys